# Sidebar not showing in Shop Page Woocommerce, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

I am quite desperate here trying to solve this. I am customizing a Wordpress Tisson Pro Theme to be WooCommerce ready (it is not). I already did what is suggested related to "Third party / custom / non-WC theme compatibility", doing it in my own Child-Theme, and 1 million things more... But the sidebar still looks not loading in the Shop Page! I inspected the code, and looks like the problem is the following;

woocommerce.php

```
<?php get_header();
$sidebar = mfn_sidebar_classes();

?>
<!-- Content -->
<div id="Content">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- .content -->
        <?php
            //open div
            if( $sidebar ) echo '<div class="content">';
            //get woocommerce content
            woocommerce_content();
            if( $sidebar ){
                //close div
                echo '</div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
            }
        ?>
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <?php
            if( $sidebar ){
                get_sidebar();
            }
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The code is not entering if( $sidebar ), somehow I cannot figure out why! I tried everything with no luck.

Please if you could help me I will really appreciate it :)

Comment: We can't know what `mfn_sidebar_classes()` returns. But if you remove the `if($sidebar)` conditional and simply call `get_sidebar()` that should work.

Comment: I already tried before this solution with no luck. the problem is that WooCommerce seems deleting every sidebar declared in the Shop Page. It is changing the layout somehow.

Comment: But is a sidebar displaying at all? Are there even any widgets in your sidebar? I would guess the layout changes because you are opening a content div with the same conditional `if( $sidebar ) echo '<div class="content">';` ... again I have no idea what the value of `$sidebar` is here because I don't know what `mfn_sidebar_classes()` returns. I would suggest you hire a developer to complete this integration... WooCommerce doesn't delete widgets or sidebars, so the problem must be with your theme.

Answer (score 1):

From the WooCommerce [Third Party Theme Compatibility](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/) docs, you should be able to just define your wrappers... which *looks* like a `<div class="content">` as far as I can tell. If you use these wrappers in `functions.php` then you do not need a `woocommerce.php`.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);

function my_theme_wrapper_start() {
  echo '<div class="content">';
}

function my_theme_wrapper_end() {
  echo '</div>';
  echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
}
```

Comment: I changed it, and now I am using just the hooks to define my wrappers. No woocommerce.php anymore. In any case, the page Shop still does not load ANY sidebar. Should I define a sidebar-shop.php or something like that?

Comment: And you definitely have some widgets in the shop sidebar? You should not have define a sidebar as WooCommerce will use its version. You can test that against Twenty Fourteen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
# WOOCOMMERCE CONNECT
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', '_woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'no_title' );
function no_title(){
    return false;
}
function _woocommerce_output_content_wrapper(){
    echo '<div class="content"><div class="entry-content">';
    genesis_do_breadcrumbs();
    echo '<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">';
    woocommerce_page_title();
    echo '</h1>';
}
```

**[>> MORE DETAILS HERE](http://www.wptaskforce.com/woocommerce-genesis-sidebar-connect/)**

Codes above will work only if the default hooks is not remove or re-positioned to different functions.

May I know your current shop URL ? In genesis, there's a page settings which you can select a page layout. You should choose sidebar-content or content-sidebar. Then  on widgets, your primary sidebar must have atleast one widgets so you will see the results. The problem on genesis and woocommerce structure is not the same. All you need to do is wrap the woocommerce HTML with the `<div class="content"><div class="entry-content">`. The structure should be like this

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <woocommerce HTML>
    </div>
</div>
<sidebar>sidebar</sidebar>
```

If the alignment is still not correct, then the problem is on your CSS codes. Second option is override you woocommerce file to your current theme and no need for using hooks in functions.php. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried this solution and is still not working. Maybe I am doing it wrong. I included this in functions.php (inside theme). I also have woocommerce.php to render the woocommerce content. I tried both in my theme and in my child theme, and in the shop page still says: "
This template supports the sidebar's widgets. Add one or use Full Width layout." when I have defined in dashboard a sidebar with a widget inside. Should I register the sidebar in functions.php and call it in woocommerce.php?

Comment: Could you please explain further what exactly means

"NOTE: If the codes below does not work, means your current Woocommerce hooks has been re-locate or Woocommerce hooks has been updated from before structure."

Comment: Actually, if I add your code my products disappear from the Shop Page

Comment: Is Tisson Pro a genesis child theme? Otherwise `genesis_do_breadcrumbs()` will cause white screen of death.

Comment: It is not, I just built it as a normal vhild without framework to work with. Do you recommend me to use it?